# How to add auto increment id to all objects in an array in Express JS and Mongodb

Tags: mongodb, express, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I am new to express js and mongodb. I have an `cinema` schema as shown below:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

var CinemaMasterSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  cinema_name: String,
  cinema_entity: String,
  start_opening_date: { type: Date },
  status: String,
  halls: []
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('CinemaMaster', CinemaMasterSchema);
```

Where it accepts halls array having objects consisting of `seat capacity`, `status`, `cinema_id` and few properties.

below is my routes file

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var cinema = require('../models/CinemaMaster.js');


router.post('/', function(req, res, next) {
  cinema.create(req.body, function (err, post) {
    if (err) return next(err);
    res.json(post);
  });
});


module.exports = router;
```

In halls array of objects, how can i add an auto increment id whenever the new cinema is created.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure I understand your question, but I believe you want each `hall` in the `halls` array to have a Mongo _id, right?

If I'm correct, then the way to go is to define `Hall` as a sub-document :

```
var HallSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  seat_capacity: Number,
  status : String
});

var CinemaMasterSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  // ...
  halls: [HallSchema]
});
```

Now every `hall` in the array wil be automatically assigned a Mongo _id.

Comment: Thank you so much you understood correctly now am getting `_id` generating in every `hall`.. And how can i store `cinemaId` in `halls`

Comment: Why would you want to store each cinema's \_id in each of their halls? That's just redundant, they _contain_ them.

Comment: No am just asking.. is it possible to store.. if yes then can u tell how can we do that?

Comment: It's a bit more complicated... You need to create the parent's \_id before saving it, then copy this \_id inside each child, then save the document in Mongo. This would deserve a whole different question on StackOverflow.

Comment: Thanks for your response.. will look into it